# How can I unwrap results from pyparsing helper functions?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm currently in the process of implementing a dialect of prolog in python. I'm using the wonderful [`pyparsing`](https://pypi.org/project/pyparsing/) module for this purpose and I've found it to work very well for other projects involving context-free grammars.

As I'm moving into context-sensitive grammars, I'm gradually getting used to `pyparsing`'s style. `pyparsing.nestedExpr` and `pyparsing.delimitedList` are two things I'm still getting acquainted with. Right now I'm having trouble with `pyparsing.delimitedList`; it achieves what I'm looking for, but each individual `term` in the example code below is returned in a list and I haven't used `pyparsing.Group` on any terms.

Refactoring to use `pyparsing.nestedExpr` and `pyparsing.infixNotation` are next on my TODOs after solving this problem, so please don't panic that I'm not using them yet. I also suspect, but don't yet know, that I'll have to  prevent matches for `term_list` on the left side of the rule expression. This is to say that the code is a work in progress and will see significant change over time as I experiment with the library further.

I think `pyparsing.ungroup` can be used to solve the problem, but `pyparsing.ungroup(pyparsing.delimitedList...` doesn't seem to have any effect in this case.

### Output Logic

```
result = root.parseString('''
A :- True
Z :- 5
''')
print(result.dump())
print(result.rules[0].goals)
```

### Results

```
[['A', 'True'], ['Z', '5']]
- rules: [['A', 'True'], ['Z', '5']]
  [0]:
    ['A', 'True']
    - goals: [['True']]
      [0]:
        ['True']
  [1]:
    ['Z', '5']
    - goals: [['5']]
      [0]:
        ['5']
[['True']]
```

### Expected Results

```
[['A', 'True'], ['Z', '5']]
- rules: [['A', 'True'], ['Z', '5']]
  [0]:
    ['A', 'True']
    - goals: ['True']
  [1]:
    ['Z', '5']
    - goals: ['5']
['True']
```

### Full Code

```
import pyparsing as pp

# These types are the language primitives
atom = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)
number = pp.Word(pp.nums)
variable = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)
string = pp.quotedString

# Terms are the basic unit of expression here
compound_term = pp.Forward()
term = (atom ^ number ^ variable ^ pp.Group(compound_term))('terms*')

# A compound term includes a few rules for term composition, such as lists or an atom containing arguments
term_list = pp.Forward()
compound_term <<= \
string ^ \
term_list ^ \
atom('functor') + pp.Suppress('(') + pp.delimitedList(term('arguments*')) + pp.Suppress(')')

term_list <<= pp.Suppress('[') + pp.delimitedList(term('items*')) + pp.Suppress(']')

# The rule operator is an infix operator represented by :-
# On the right side, multiple goals can be composed using AND or OR operators
rule = pp.Group(
    term + pp.Suppress(':-') + \
    pp.delimitedList(term('goals*')) \
    )('rules*')

root = pp.ZeroOrMore(rule)

result = root.parseString(
    '''
    A :- True
    Z :- 5
    ''')
print(result.dump())
print(result.rules[0].goals)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial problem is the presence of `Group` in `compound_term`:

```
term = (atom ^ number ^ variable ^ pp.Group(compound_term))('terms*')
```

should be

```
term = (atom ^ number ^ variable ^ (compound_term))('terms*')
```

After making that change, and adding a "lhs" results name in your rule (see below), I get this:

```
[['A', 'True'], ['Z', '5']]
- rules: [['A', 'True'], ['Z', '5']]
  [0]:
    ['A', 'True']
    - goals: ['True']
    - lhs: 'A'
  [1]:
    ['Z', '5']
    - goals: ['5']
    - lhs: 'Z'
['True']
```

Some added notes:

1. `atom` is defined as

   ```
   atom = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)
   ```

   This will match "123" as an `atom` also. To ensure that you just get variable *names* , use `pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.alphanums)`. This indicates that the initial letter must be an alpha, and any subsequent letters can be alpha or numeric (same for `variable`).
2. I would not add the results name "terms*" on term, since it will end up getting used on both left and right hand sides of your ":-" operator. I recommend that people *generally* leave the attachment of results names until the expression is used in higher-level expressions. For instance, I would define rule as:

   ```
   rule = pp.Group(term("rule_lhs") 
                   + ":-" 
                   + pp.delimitedList(term)("goals") 
                   )
   ```
3. I wouldn't really call ":-" an "infix" operator, I consider operators like "+", "-", "AND", "OR" as infix operators. For instance, I don't think `x :- y :- z` is valid. You'll probably do something like this to add your "AND" and "OR" operators:

   ```
   logical_term_expression = pp.infixNotation(term,
               [
               ("&&", 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT,),
               ("||", 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT,),
               ])
   ```

   Having a results name in `term` will really make a mess of this, more likely to use classes on your operator tuples, as you can see in the pyparsing examples like simple_bool.py.
4. You mentioned using `nestedExpr` - please don't. That helper is best used when writing a scanner for something like C code, where you might want to just jump over some nested braces without actually parsing the contents. In your DSL, you will want to parse everything properly - but I think `infixNotation` may be all you need.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response! I've marked this as the correct answer owing to the variety of best practice recommendations you've included as well as having the solution that I implemented independently. While I'm somewhat uncomfortable using "lhs" instead of something more specific to the expression, that's mostly a matter of style. I apologize for the delay!